# How to install mysql workbench on linux debian 10 (Google Pixelbook)

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, debian-buster, chrome-os

*I first asked this question on StackOverflow but someone told me there that I have a better chance of getting an answer here*

I am trying to install MySQL Workbench on my Google Pixelbook. It runs Linux debian 10 buster.

So I run these commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

and then

`sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench`

I get this error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: gdal-abi-2-1-2
                   Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libmysqlcppconn7v5 (>= 1.1.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ttf-bitstream-vera but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: mysql-utilities but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install these dependencies it is a never-ending story of missing dependencies like described in this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005179/unable-to-install-mysql-workbench-for-ubuntu-16-04-lts

I searched a lot on several forum for a solution but nothing works. Most solutions I found was for Ubuntu and not for Debian

FYI, at first I tried to install it by downloading and installing the following file `mysql-workbench-community_8.0.23-1ubuntu20.10_amd64.deb` and it didn't work.. Maybe it created some kind of conflict that prevents me from installing it with `apt` or `apt-get`

Here is the content `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
  GNU nano 3.2                                               /etc/apt/sources.list                                                         

# Generated by distrobuilder
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
```

Thanks

When I try to purge I got this:

`sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench-community`
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql-workbench-community which isn't installed`
`sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench`
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql-workbench which isn't installed`

And when I try to install with snapd I got this

`sudo snap install core`

`error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:/tmp/sanity-mountpoint-750692798: mount failed: Operation not permitted.`

Snapd and snap are installed:

`sudo apt list snapd -a`

```
Listing... Done
snapd/stable,now 2.37.4-1+b1 amd64 [installed]
snapd/oldstable 2.21-2+b1 amd64
```

`sudo apt list snap -a`

```
Listing... Done
snap/stable,now 2013-11-29-9 amd64 [installed]
snap/oldstable 2013-11-29-6 amd64
```

What are your thoughts dear community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was caused by the fact that chromeos was not dealing well with snapd

Found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859806/chromeos-error-system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-imag

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the dependency conflicts are likely due to the `.deb` install.

Specifically, the `.deb` has lots of dependencies that are not available in your upstream repositories.

#### Cleanup

First, get back to a clean state.

```
dpkg --purge mysql-workbench
apt-get autoremove
```

#### Snap

In this case, I suggest you try `snapd`, which is a different package manager that focuses on allowing developers to publish directly to users, rather than using distribution maintainers.

- **pro:** faster release cycles
- **con:** less assurance of stability/compatibility since it is not packaged by distribution maintainers.

In this case, the package you want is not in the main Debian repository, so snap is a good fallback.

#### Install

```
apt update
apt install snapd
snap install core
snap install mysql-workbench-community
```

Comment: Thanks

When I try to purge I got this:

`sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench-community`
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql-workbench-community which isn't installed`
`sudo dpkg --purge mysql-workbench`
`dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove mysql-workbench which isn't installed`

And when I try to install with snapd I got this

`sudo snap install core`

`error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-750692798: mount failed: Operation not permitted.`

Snapd and snap are installed

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859806/chromeos-error-system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-imag Thanks!

Comment: @LouisChaussé great. You should also remove the `stretch` sources in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Mixing versions in your repository sources is not a good idea.